# How to display Airflow DAG status in Big Query tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I want to show the DAG (airflow) final status (success/Failure) to a table in BQ.
Like that table can contains: Date-Time,DAG-Name,Status etc columns and it will get populated according to the final status of the DAG.

Please help; how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native out-of-the-box method to achieve this in Airflow. However, you could implement a function yourself which writes data to BigQuery and run it via a DAG's `on_success_callback` and `on_failure_callback` methods.

Note: BigQuery is not a transactional database and has limits on the number of inserts per day. For a large number of DAG runs, you might want to think of writing results in batches to BigQuery.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. Working on to write python functions to be called from DAG's on_success_callback and on_failure_callback methods.

Comment: hi @sayantibhattacharjee, did it work the way as suggested by Bas. If so, can you share more details regarding the way you implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the data in real-time, I would go with somethign along the lines of the approach @Bas has suggested, maybe with firestore or Cloud SQL.  However note his comments on the inserts per day if you go with BigQuery.

If you can wait on the results on a daily basis you can do a log sink to BigQuery as described here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs#stackdriver_logging_exports

In the filter criteria you can either bring in all of the Airflow logs or just the ones from the worker/scheduler.

Ex criteria:

```
resource.type="cloud_composer_environment"
logName="projects/{YOUR-PROJECT}/logs/airflow-worker"
```

In the log textPayload you will see something like:

```
Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=thing, task_id=stuff, executiondate=20220307T111111, start_date=20220307T114858, end_date=20220307T114859
```

You can then parse for what you need in BigQuery

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answer of user `Bas Harenslak`. There are these options also that you can explore:

- You can make use of [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html). By using it  you can have one dag (a `recap-dag`) which will be referenced by your DAGs to populate the record into your destination dataset.

```
trigger_recap_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(
      task_id="trigger_recap_dag",
      trigger_dag_id="recap-dag",
      wait_for_completion=False,
      allowed_states=['success']
      conf='{"Time": datetime.now() ,"DAG": "recap-dag","Status":"success"}'
  )

ingestion >> transformation >> save >> send_notification >> trigger_recap_dag
```

- If you see fit, This `recap-dag` can also be independent and only run every hour/day/week of your election and checks your DAGs status.

```
with DAG(
  'recap-dag',
  schedule_interval='@daily',
  start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
  catchup=False, 
) as dag:

  ...
  # Airflow >= 2.0.0
  # Inside a python Operator
  def GetRunningDagsInfo():
     dag_runs = DagRun.find(
       dag_id=your_dag_id,
       execution_start_date=your_start_date
       execution_end_date=your_end_date
     )
    
  ...
```

- You can make use of prior options and come with a solution like this:

> After you dag (or dags) complete, it will fire the trigger dag. this `recap-dag` will saves your dag records into a custom table or
> file and then your independent DAG runs and retrieves the datasets
> that have been created so far and push the data into your BigQuery
> Table.

- Another option is by looking into your Airflow Database to retrieve running information. Know as [Data Profiling](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/profiling.html). It has been deprecated in latest versions due to security concerns.